# MongoDB Load related documents count without $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got 2 collections `locations` and `users` in mongodb database which every user has a `location` attribute:

`locations` Collection:

```json
{
  "_id": "62de2eebefdaab015e668929",
  "title": "New York"
}
```

`users` Collection:

```json
{
  "_id": "27de2ccbefdaab01545684a",
  "name": "James Brown",
  "location": "62de2eebefdaab015e668929"
}
```

I need to retrieve every locations with it's population. So just used $lookup and $addField aggregation on `locations` collection:

```json
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "location",
      "as": "users",
    }
  },
  {
    "$addField": {
      "usersCount": {
        "$size": "$users"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Theoretically it gets the correct answer, however it takes long times to answer and sometimes even fails due to memory limit reach. Because the amount of users per location might be huge.

Since I just need the count of users in each location, Not the whole users data, Is there a better way to count related documents without actually loading all of them into memory using `$lookup`?

Answer (score 1):

How about starting the aggregation from the `users` collection? You can do  `$group` to get the count. You can then perform a less intense `$lookup` to retrieve info from the `locations` collection.

For your memory limit issue, you might want to check out [$lookup + $unwind coalesce optimization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup----unwind-coalescence).

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$location",
      "userCount": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "locations",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "locationLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$locationLookup",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J6-KLFfgQGm) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a good idea. But after implementation,Turns out It's even more time/memory consuming than the first approach. Of course the question is a little simplified and `location` attribute is an array in real world problem. So I had to `$unwind` the `location` property before `$group` which produces a large number of documents and takes down the query performance seriously

Comment: @SaeidAsadi you may consider indexing the location field to speed up the `$lookup` and `$group`. HTH.

Comment: Yes I have used indexes already.

Comment: @SaeidAsadi Can you try to use a subpipeline like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8CuZPWe4PJU) to see whether it helps?